# Prove $h^{-1}fh \in K_4$ for $f\in K_4$, $h\in S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> I want to show if  $f \in K_4=\{id,(1 2)(3 4),(1 3)(2 4),(1 4)(2 3)\}$, then for all permutations $h \in S_4$ also $h^{-1}fh \in K_4$ (not using group theory).

The elements in $K_4$ except for the identity are the elements in $S_4$ which are a product of two disjoint 2-cycles.

Therefore, I am trying to prove that $h^{-1}fh$ in disjoint cycle notation are two 2-cycles.

Then I consider different cycle structures of $h$, $4$ 1-cycles, one 3-cycle and one 1-cycle etc.

However, I am not sure why it is true for instance if $h$ is $(1)(2 3 4)$, taking the $f$ to be the identity I get $(1)(2)(3 4)$ which is not two 2-cycles.

Comment: You made a mistake in the example you mention. The result is the identity.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to show is that $K_4$ is a *normal subgroup* of $S_4$.

---

However, you said you wish not to use group theory. No problem.

> **Theorem:** For any $n\in\Bbb N$ and permutations $\alpha,\beta\in S_n$ with
>
> $$\beta=\prod_{i}(b_{i,1}\cdots b_{i,j_i}),$$
>
> we have that
>
> $$\alpha^{-1}\beta\alpha=\prod_{i}(\alpha(b_{i,1})\cdots \alpha(b_{i,j_i})),\tag{1}$$
>
> where $\alpha(x)$ is $\alpha$ applied to $x\in \overline{1,n}:=\{1,\dots, n\}$, and the cycle structure of $\beta$ is preserved in the RHS of $(1)$.

Then one just needs to observe that each $h\in S_4$ is a bijection on $\overline{1,4} $, so that the disjoint cycle nature of each $f$ in $K_4$ is preserved.

---

And as [Tobias pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027394/prove-h-1fh-in-k-4-for-f-in-k-4-h-in-s-4?r=SearchResults#comment4161023_2027394), you made an error in your calculation.